# Preventing font scale in QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, font-size, zooming, qgraphicstextitem

I am using **QGraphicsTextItem** to paint the text on the scene. Text is painted along the path (**QGraphicsPathItem**), wich is parent of my **QGraphicsTextItem** - so the text rotation is changed to be along the path element and is sticked to it while zooming the view. But the font size of **QGraphicsTextItem** is also changing while zooming the view - this is what I am trying to avoid. Of I set **QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations** flag to the **QGraphicsTextItem** it stops rotating while it's parent (**QGraphicsPathItem**) does.

[image]

I do understand that I have to re-implement **QGraphicsTextItem::paint** function, but I am stuck with the coordination system. Here is the code (**Label** class inherits public **QGraphicsTextItem**):

```
void Label::paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget )
{
    // Store current position and rotation
    QPointF position = pos();
    qreal angle = rotation();

    // Store current transformation matrix
    QTransform transform = painter->worldTransform();

    // Reset painter transformation
    painter->setTransform( QTransform() );

    // Rotate painter to the stored angle
    painter->rotate( angle );

    // Draw the text
    painter->drawText( mapToScene( position ), toPlainText() );

    // Restore transformation matrix
    painter->setTransform( transform );
}
```

The position (and rotation) of my text on the screen is unpredictable :(
What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a QGraphicsTextItem: ignoring transformations causes an apparent shift in position with a different view scale. I believe that centering might resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked perfectly for me:

```
void MyDerivedQGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const StyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    double scaleValue = scale()/painter->transform().m11();
    painter->save();
    painter->scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
    painter->drawText(...);
    painter->restore();
    ...
}
```

We can also multiply the scaleValue by other mesures we want to keep its size constant outside the save/restore environment.

```
QPointF ref(500, 500);
QPointF vector = scaleValue * QPointF(100, 100);
painter->drawLine(ref+vector, ref-vector);
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved a problem this way - for drawing a line/circle/rectangle/path, *which I want to be transformed*, I use an appropriate **QGraphicsLine**/**Ellipse**/**Rect**/**PathItem**. For drawing the text (*which I do NOT want to be transformed*) I use **QGraphicsSimpleTextItem**. I set text's flag to ignore transormations and set it's parent to Line/Ellipse/Rect/Path item. The Line/Ellipse/Rect/Path item transforms, but text does not - this is what I wanted. I can also rotate text and set it's position.
Thank you very much for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once. Instead of ignoring transformations, you need to scale down the items you don't want to be zoomed in in your zoom-in function.

When you zoom in, if you change the scale by `ds` for example, scale the items by `1.0 / ds`

You might need to change their positions though.

I hope this helps.

Edit: I hope I understood the question right.